# Prove or disprove: The Cauchy-product of series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{k}}$ equals...

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

> Prove or disprove: The Cauchy-product of series
>   $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{k}}$ and
>   $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{k}}$ equals
>   $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(2^{1-k}-2^{-2k} \right )$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k}^{l}\frac{1}{2^{l}}\cdot \frac{1}{4^{k-l}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k}^{l}2^{-l}\cdot 4^{-k+l}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k}^{l}2^{-l}\cdot 4^{-k}\cdot 4^{l}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{l}\cdot 4^{-k}$$

As it looks like, the statement is false.

Did I do everything correctly?

Comment: Your final result does not make sense, because it still involves $l$ even though there is no longer a summation over $l$.

Comment: How can I remove this $l$ and the second sum symbol? I have no idea..

Comment: You want $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^k 2^{-l} 4^{-(k-l)}$. Now use the geometric series formula twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual Cauchy product is supposed to be:$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^k 2^{-l}4^{l-k}= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^k 2^{-l}2^{l-k} 2^{l-k} =\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-2k}\sum_{l=0}^k 2^l=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-2k}(2^{k+1}-1)  $$

So the statement is true.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't understand the end, what happened to sum of $2^{l}$? You just removed it because there was no $k$ left anywhere, or..?

Comment: @cnmesr sum of a geometric series $$\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Statement is true.
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{t=0}^{k}(\frac{1}{2^{t}}\cdot \frac{1}{4^{k-t}})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{t=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{2k-t}}$$
Since $$\sum_{t=0}^{k}\frac{1}{2^{2k-t}}=\frac{1}{2^k}\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{2k}},$$
we have $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{2k}}=2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{2k}}$$
$$S=2\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=4-\frac{4}{3}=\frac{8}{3}$$